# Jenkins OpenLDAP plugin authentication fails, but lookup is successful

Tags: docker, plugins, ldap, jenkins

I've setup an OpenLDAP server with following structure:

```
dn: dc=test-project,dc=com objectclass: top objectclass: dcObject objectclass: organization


dn: cn=admin,dc=test-project,dc=com
description: LDAP administrator
objectclass: simpleSecurityObject
objectclass: organizationalRole

ou=applications,dc=test-project,dc=com
dn: ou=applications,dc=test-project,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: applications

uid=devopstools,ou=applications,dc=test-project,dc=com
dn: uid=devopstools,ou=applications,dc=test-project,dc=com
objectclass: account
objectclass: simpleSecurityObject
objectclass: top
uid: devopstools

ou=groups,dc=test-project,dc=com
dn: ou=groups,dc=test-project,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: groups

cn=administrators,ou=groups,dc=test-project,dc=com
dn: cn=administrators,ou=groups,dc=test-project,dc=com
gidnumber: 500
objectclass: posixGroup
objectclass: top

cn=users,ou=groups,dc=test-project,dc=com
dn: cn=users,ou=groups,dc=test-project,dc=com
gidnumber: 501
objectclass: posixGroup
objectclass: top

ou=users,dc=test-project,dc=com
dn: ou=users,dc=test-project,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: users

cn=test,ou=users,dc=test-project,dc=com
dn: cn=test,ou=users,dc=test-project,dc=com
cn: test
gidnumber: 500
givenname: Test
homedirectory: /home/users/test
mail: test@prova.com
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: posixAccount
objectclass: top
sn: test
uid: test
uidnumber: 1002
```

I configured it to work with gogs and all seem work fine. So I moved to configure LDAP plugin for Jenkins with this parameters:

```
server: openldap.test.svc.cluster.local
root DN: dc=test-project,dc=com
User search filter: cn={0}
Group membership:gidnumber
Manager DN:cn=admin,dc=test-project,dc=com
password:xxxx
```

Now, when I test LDAP connection with "admin" user or "devopstools" user I get user Lookup and Authentication successful, instead when I use "test" user I get only user lookup successful and Authentication failed!
The all passwords are stored in SSHA hash.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same issue, and I'm not able to solve it yet. 
Did you get a solution to this?

The only way that I find may be a workaround is to give read permission to the Test account, but that isn't a good approach. The only account that needs to be able
to read the LDAP Tree is the admin account configured as the ManagerDN.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I have modified the ACL on OpenLDAP in this way:

`olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by dn="cn=admin, dc=test-project,dc=com" write by anonymous auth by * none`

`olcAccess: {1}to * by self read by dn="uid=devopstools,ou=applications, dc=test-project,dc=com" read by dn="cn=admin,dc=test-project,dc=com" write by * no`